# WPF Scrollviewer ItemsControl Scroll Item Into View

Tags: wpf, vb.net, itemscontrol, scrollviewer

I have a WPF Scrollviewer with its content as an Items Control which displays a list of images. I then have another scrollviewer with an Items control which hold the selected images. What I need to do is when some clicks the selected image, the item in the all images should scroll in to view.

I have searched around but couldn't find any examples of how to achieve this.

Anybody have any examples or suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you need to call bring into view on your SelectedItem's Container as such :

```
    var container = yourItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(yourItemsControl.SelectedItem) as FrameworkElement;
    if (container != null)
        container.BringIntoView();
```

you should do this in a custom Behavior on selection changed.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I am having problems getting it to work. I have put the code in the MouseLeftDown event of the image, is this right?